How do I synchronize the scroll of two multiline text boxes with wxPython?
I'm currently in the process of coding an application with wxPython, in Python 3.12. The app contains two multiline text boxes, side by side: the box on the left takes user input, and the box on the right is filled by the program with line-specific feedback about the user input.

When the user inputs text longer than however many lines, scrollbars appear in each box--but when the user scrolls down in one box, the other stays still, misaligning the line feedback and making it difficult to determine where the program indicates a problem has been found.
Extensive internet research has failed to give any working solutions to this issue. This page How to sync the scrollbars of two grids in wx contains a similar, but not identical problem. However, it uses Python 2, and in consequence the code no longer compiles into anything meaningful. Can anyone help?
Thanks!
### Pottersclay Writing Assistant 2.2a (MRE) ###
import wx
# Initialize the window
app = wx.App()
window = wx.Frame(None, title = "Pottersclay Writing Assistant 2.2a (MRE)", size = (1885, 1010))
window.Show()
bkg = wx.Panel(window, style = wx.WANTS_CHARS)
# Create the two main text boxes and set their styles
contents = wx.TextCtrl(bkg, pos = (0, 35), size = (500, 400), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL | wx.WANTS_CHARS)
outputbox = wx.TextCtrl(bkg, pos = (0, 35), size = (500, 400), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL | wx.WANTS_CHARS | wx.TE_READONLY)
contents.SetWindowStyle(contents.GetWindowStyle() & ~ wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
outputbox.SetWindowStyle(outputbox.GetWindowStyle() & ~ wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
EXAMPLE = "0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n41\n42\n43\n44\n45\n46\n47\n48\n49\n"
contents.SetValue(EXAMPLE)
outputbox.SetValue(EXAMPLE)
#Add the two text boxes and the button box to a new, horizontal box sizer representing all of the window below the command line
lowerhbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
lowerhbox.Add(contents, proportion = 1, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.BOTTOM | wx.LEFT, border = 5)
lowerhbox.Add(outputbox, proportion = 1, flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.BOTTOM | wx.RIGHT, border = 5)
bkg.SetSizer(lowerhbox)
app.MainLoop()


Here is my answer. It can only synchronize the scrolling of both sides of the text box, not the content.
### Pottersclay Writing Assistant 2.2a (MRE) ###
import wx

# Initialize the window
app = wx.App()
window = wx.Frame(None, title="Pottersclay Writing Assistant 2.2a (MRE)", size=(1885, 1010))
bkg = wx.Panel(window, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
# Create the two main text boxes and set their styles
contents = wx.TextCtrl(
    bkg, pos=(0, 35), size=(500, 400), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL | wx.WANTS_CHARS
)
outputbox = wx.TextCtrl(
    bkg,
    pos=(0, 35),
    size=(500, 400),
    style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL | wx.WANTS_CHARS | wx.TE_READONLY,
)
contents.SetWindowStyle(contents.GetWindowStyle() & ~wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
outputbox.SetWindowStyle(outputbox.GetWindowStyle() & ~wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
EXAMPLE = "0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n41\n42\n43\n44\n45\n46\n47\n48\n49\n"
contents.SetValue(EXAMPLE)
outputbox.SetValue(EXAMPLE)
# Add the two text boxes and the button box to a new, horizontal box sizer representing all of the window below the command line
lowerhbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
lowerhbox.Add(contents, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.BOTTOM | wx.LEFT, border=5)
lowerhbox.Add(outputbox, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.BOTTOM | wx.RIGHT, border=5)
bkg.SetSizer(lowerhbox)
window.Show()  # CHANGE: Make the widget can be layout

### ADDED CODE ###
handing = False  # Flag if the mouse scroll event is being processed

def scroll_handler(event: wx.MouseEvent):
    global handing
    handing = True
    print("Mouse wheel event", event.GetWheelRotation())
    if event.GetEventObject() == contents:
        outputbox.ScrollLines(int(event.WheelRotation / -40))
    else:
        contents.ScrollLines(int(event.WheelRotation / -40))
    handing = False
    event.Skip()


def bar_handler(event: wx.ScrollWinEvent):
    if handing:
        event.Skip()
        return
    print("Window has been scrolled", event.GetPosition())
    if event.GetEventObject() == contents:
        outputbox.ShowPosition(event.GetPosition() * 3)
    else:
        contents.ShowPosition(event.GetPosition() * 3)
    event.Skip()


outputbox.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, scroll_handler)
contents.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, scroll_handler)
outputbox.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, bar_handler)
contents.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, bar_handler)
#  The function "wx.TextCtrl().ScrollLines" will trig the event "wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN" when the scroll event is processed.
### ADDED CODE ###

app.MainLoop()


I tried it, but the scrolling was sporadic...it worked at first, but as I continued to scroll, the two text boxes simply stopped syncing.

Now it can work rightly.
+++++++
### Pottersclay Writing Assistant 2.2a (MRE) ###
import wx

# Initialize the window
app = wx.App()
window = wx.Frame(None, title="Pottersclay Writing Assistant 2.2a (MRE)", size=(1885, 1010))
bkg = wx.Panel(window, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
# Create the two main text boxes and set their styles
contents = wx.TextCtrl(
    bkg, pos=(0, 35), size=(500, 400), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL | wx.WANTS_CHARS
)
outputbox = wx.TextCtrl(
    bkg,
    pos=(0, 35),
    size=(500, 400),
    style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL | wx.WANTS_CHARS | wx.TE_READONLY,
)
contents.SetWindowStyle(contents.GetWindowStyle() & ~wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
outputbox.SetWindowStyle(outputbox.GetWindowStyle() & ~wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
EXAMPLE = "0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n41\n42\n43\n44\n45\n46\n47\n48\n49\n"
contents.SetValue(EXAMPLE)
outputbox.SetValue(EXAMPLE)
# Add the two text boxes and the button box to a new, horizontal box sizer representing all of the window below the command line
lowerhbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
lowerhbox.Add(contents, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.BOTTOM | wx.LEFT, border=5)
lowerhbox.Add(outputbox, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.BOTTOM | wx.RIGHT, border=5)
bkg.SetSizer(lowerhbox)
window.Show()  # CHANGE: Make the widget can be layout

### ADDED CODE ###
handing = False  # Flag if the mouse scroll event is being processed

def scroll_handler(event: wx.MouseEvent):
    global handing
    if handing:
        event.Skip()
        return
    handing = True
    print("Mouse wheel event", event.GetWheelRotation())
    if event.GetEventObject() == contents:
        outputbox.ScrollLines(int(event.WheelRotation / -40))
    else:
        contents.ScrollLines(int(event.WheelRotation / -40))
    handing = False
    event.Skip()


def bar_handler(event: wx.ScrollWinEvent):
    global handing
    if handing:
        event.Skip()
        return
    handing = True
    print("Window has been scrolled", event.GetPosition())
    if event.GetEventObject() == contents:
        outputbox.ShowPosition(event.GetPosition() * 3)
    else:
        contents.ShowPosition(event.GetPosition() * 3)
    handing = False
    event.Skip()


outputbox.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, scroll_handler)
contents.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, scroll_handler)
outputbox.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, bar_handler)
contents.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, bar_handler)
#  The function "wx.TextCtrl().ScrollLines" will trig the event "wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN" when the scroll event is processed.
### ADDED CODE ###

app.MainLoop()


Still not working... https://ibb.co/R2LCqLY
Scroll around for a few seconds and it just goes out of sync.
